# heroku App not compatible with buildpack with git

Tags: git, heroku, branch

I have problem with git
I want to push my app and I am getting this error

```
~/drsprayfoam/spray-foam-insulation [master]$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 50, done.
Counting objects: 100% (50/50), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (45/45), done.
Writing objects: 100% (49/49), 129.25 KiB | 3.40 MiB/s, done.
Total 49 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to drsprayfoam.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/drsprayfoam.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/drsprayfoam.git'



   $  heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
     ›   Error: Multiple apps in git remotes
     ›      Usage: --remote origin
     ›         or: --app drsprayfoam
     ›      Your local git repository has more than 1 app referenced in git remotes.
     ›      Because of this, we can't determine which app you want to run this command against.
     ›      Specify the app you want with --app or --remote.
     ›      Heroku remotes in repo:
     ›      drsprayfoam (heroku)
     ›   drsprayfoam (origin)
     ›
     ›      https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/drsprayfoam.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/drsprayfoam.git (push)
origin  https://git.heroku.com/drsprayfoam.git (fetch)
origin  https://git.heroku.com/drsprayfoam.git (push)
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer as it is no longer relevant to the updated question, I have no experience with buildpacks but changing the title hopefully makes visible to someone who can help

Comment: @BeppeC thank you for trying :) I am so bad with git. I think this should solve first Error: Multiple apps in git remotes